Duplicate Metrice are sent by openlit
I'm using openlit for genai tracing
Once the function is called and got the response, the openlit is sending request log properly to Kibana, But the issue is with usage tokens/cost calculation. After the LLM call is done the calculation is happening and sending it to kibana, but it's not stopping the same log is sent to kibana every minute until i stop the server (flask).
llm_response = ""
with start_trace(name="completions") as trace:
    meta_data = get_trace_meta_data()
    trace._span.set_attributes(meta_data)
    formatted_messages = self.format_messages(messages)
    llm_response = self.model.chat(
        messages=formatted_messages,
        user=meta_data.get("userId"),
    )
    llm_response = str(llm_response).replace("assistant:", "").strip()
return llm_response

What could be the reason?
